# How to echo only the result and not the whole page in ajax call

Tags: php, json, ajax, get

I have a JavaScript page which makes a call to a PHP page.

```
$.getJSON('result.php', function(json){
    var data = json.result[0];
}).complete(function(){        
// do this
}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {        
// do this
});
```

This is how result.php looks like

```
require_once('config.php');

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF8");
$apiMgr = new API(0, 0, array("result"));
$apiResult =  $apiMgr->callAPI('GET', 'result', isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) && $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] == '/historical' ? '?option=follow' : null, null);
echo $apiResult;
```

In the config page i have added some javascript script like follwoing

```
<script>
  // script
  // script
  // script
  // script
</script>
```

The problem is $.getJSON() gives me syntax error because the whole response from result.php also includes the script part which shouldn't be there.

I want to only echo or return the $apiResult not the whole page. I hope I have explained my problem if it is not clear I will try to explain it more.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $apiResult;
exit();
```

You need to stop the header buffering

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I am just wondering why? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the header just before the `echo` statement. And also, terminate the script execution after printing it out.

```
$apiMgr = new API(0, 0, array("result"));
$apiResult =  $apiMgr->callAPI('GET', 'result', isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) && $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] == '/historical' ? '?option=follow' : null, null);

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF8");
echo $apiResult;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

from your question I figure out that you're not encoding your echo part in json
try to

```
echo json_encode($apiResult);
```

hope it'll work

Answer (score -1):

you need to have an other config.php without script tags. Or add a condition to your config.php and test if we need to show your script tags.

```
    $.get('result.php', function(data){
        var data = json.result[0];
    }).complete(function(){        
    // do this
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {        
    // do this
    });

    function callbackfunction(data){
        //do something
    }

    //in your result.php 

    require_once('config.php');

    $apiMgr = new API(0, 0, array("result"));
    $apiResult =  $apiMgr->callAPI('GET', 'result', isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) && $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] == '/historical' ? '?option=follow' : null, null);
    echo '';
    echo 'callbackfunction('.$apiResult.')';
    echo '';
```

Comment: I need to have these script tags in my config file. This is important script and I cannot afford to remove it. It would be great to exclude this somehow in the output.

Comment: the problem is when you send a request with $.getJSON, this method need to get only a json format text. With your script tags it's impossible to work beacause your header is already send.

Comment: you can do something like that : 
`code` $.get('result.php', function(data){
    var data = json.result[0];}).complete(function(){        
}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
});
function callbackfunction(data){
 //do something
}
//in your result.php 
require_once('config.php');$apiMgr = new API(0, 0, array("result"));$apiResult =  $apiMgr->callAPI('GET', 'result', isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) && $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] == '/historical' ? '?option=follow' : null, null);echo '<script type="text/javascript">';echo 'callbackfunction('.$apiResult.')';echo '</script>';`code`